# Linux- Add/Insert in only the secondlast line with a new value keeping original content intact in same file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, vi, in-place

I need to add/insert a value "new content" on the secondlast line of the same file without deleting any of the lines or content of my file.

**The condition is that the file content keeps changing and line numbers do not remain fixed.**

Sample file:

```
library_path="usr/lib/1.0"
if test -n "/usr/local/lib64"; then
: ${PATH=${HOME}/lib:/usr/local/lib64}
else
: ${L_PATH=${HOME}/lib}
fi
if test -n "/usr/local/libs"; then
: ${PATH=${HOME}/lib:/usr/local/}
fi
##comment1
#comment2
##comment3
#comment4
if vals"${PATH}"; then
  PATH="${L_PATH}"
else
  PATH="${LD_PATH}:${Y_PATH}"
fi
export LD_PATH
```

I am trying the below command but its inserting the content on every line of the file:

```
sed -i 'x; s/.*/new content/;p;x; $d' myfile.txt
```

Any help appreciated !!

Comment: i am looking for a linux command which will add text `new content` on second last line of the file irrespective if the number of lines/content of file changes dynamically

Comment: Do you mean *replace* that line with `new content`, or *append* `new content` to that line, or *insert* `new content` as the second-to-last line? Please show us your desired output.

Comment: @Beta Below is the desired output, but the condition is that the file content keeps changing and i want to append a string everytime on second-last line only without deleting existing content and in the same file:  ```library_path="usr/lib/1.0"
if test -n "/usr/local/lib64"; then
: ${PATH=${HOME}/lib:/usr/local/lib64}
else
: ${L_PATH=${HOME}/lib}
fi
if test -n "/usr/local/libs"; then
: ${PATH=${HOME}/lib:/usr/local/}
fi
##comment1
#comment2
##comment3
#comment4
if vals"${PATH}"; then
  PATH="${L_PATH}"
else
  PATH="${LD_PATH}:${Y_PATH}"
fi
new content
export LD_PATH```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert "`new content`" line as the second-to-last line into the file, use the Perl one-liner below. Example of usage:

```
echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" > in_file
perl -i.bak -ne 'push @a, $_; if ( eof ) { print for ( @a[0 .. ($#a-1)], "new content\n", $a[-1] ); }' in_file
```

Input:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
new content
baz
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`push @a, $_;` : Add the current line that was read from the input file into array `@a`. Thus, at the end of the file (`eof`), `@a` has the entire input file contents, 1 line per array element.
`@a[0 .. ($#a-1)]` : Lines 1 through the next-to-last line (inclusive). Note that arrays in Perl are 0-indexed.
`$a[-1]` : Last line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: I wanted the `new content` line to be part of the same original file `myfile.txt` and not in a new file ..... i am looking an equivalent to `sed -i`

Comment: @AutomationEngr Added a method using `-i` switch, without using temp file. This Perl option is similar to `sed -i`.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Great, This was what I was looking for. `sed -i` had some issues on my pc's linux version so i think i will go with perl, thanks again.